# When is the least-area surface unique?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, calculus-of-variations, geometric-analysis, minimal-surfaces

Let $M^{n-1}$ be a smooth closed manifold, embedded into the round sphere $\mathbf{S}^n$ via a regular map $\Phi$. Using tools from geometric measure theory, one can prove the existence of a $n$-dimensional current $T$ in the ball $B \subset \mathbf{R}^{n+1}$ with $\partial T = \Phi(M)$, which has the least area among all such surfaces.

**Question.** What is known regarding the generic uniqueness of $T$? How does this relate to the regularity of $\Phi$: for example if it is in $C^{k,\alpha}$, $C^\infty$ or $C^\omega$?

- I vaguely remember seeing some results asserting the generic uniqueness in the Baire sense, but I can't find the paper now. The literature on the Plateau problem is honestly too vast...
- I'd be most interested in results that establish uniqueness in a stronger sense, for example unless $\Phi$ belongs to some space of embeddings $M \to \mathbf{S}^n$ with quantifiable codimension.

Comment: By quantifiable codimension, do you mean finite co-dimension? Because I would assume that as long as there aren't two solutions with the same tangent-space at almost all boundary points (which I guess is even more rare than non-uniqueness), I can always slightly wiggle around one of these boundary points to favor one or the other solution and thus gain uniqueness in an infinite dimensional number of ways.

Comment: @mlk Loosely speaking I meant that $T$ be unique unless $\Phi$ belongs to some 'bad' set of maps $M \to \mathbf{S}^n$ which is 'small in some strong sense'. It would have been more precise to write finite codimension; I was trying to express some flexibility. As to the rest of your comment, I'm not sure I completely follow the point you're making. Could you reformulate it or elaborate on it?

Comment: I think this might be the paper you are remembering: https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=653546 . Im not sure if the paper specifically answers your question but I think it will be relevant.

Comment: @LeoMoos Wouldn't the exceptional set then be of finite dimension and not co-dimension? In any case, I think that is also not true, even if you discount reparametrization: Take a non-unique situation (such as the two circles for which the corresponding catenoid and two-disc solutions have the same area) and then add a small closed curve somewhere far away. Now the minimal surface will always split into one of the old solutions and a small surface for the curve. Thus you have non-uniqueness for any such curve, of which there are infinite-dimensionally many.

Comment: @OtisChodosh Thanks Otis, I'll take a look.

Comment: @mlk You're right, that's a typo. To avoid the kind of example you're referring to in the second part of your comment, I wouldn't mind imposing that $M$ be connected. I'll update the question later.